# Complex text alignment on a UILabel

Tags: uilabel, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring

I want to align a date in a table cell (UILabel type) as follows:

```
Monday     03 May
Tuesday    04 May
Wednesday  05 May
```

I tried to use Attributed Strings as follows:

```
    CTTextTabRef tabArray[] = { CTTextTabCreate(0, 12, NULL) }; // try 12 and see how it goes
    CFArrayRef tabStops = CFArrayCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**) tabArray, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks );
    CTParagraphStyleSetting altSettings[] =
    {
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierTabStops, sizeof(CFArrayRef), &tabStops },
    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate( altSettings, sizeof(altSettings) / sizeof(CTParagraphStyleSetting) );

    NSDictionary *dictionaryForATab = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:(__bridge NSObject *)style, (NSString *)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

    NSString *dateString = [self stringFromDate:date]; // returns something like this--> @"Monday \t 03 May"
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:dateString attributes:dictionaryForATab];
```

But I get a

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x951b8e0'
```

error.

Any ideas on how to fix it (or another way of doing the same thing)?

(Obviously using Courier (or any monospaced font) and space-padding the weekdays,
is not a valid answer. I am looking for something more sophisticated.)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm getting exactly the same exception out of some NSAttributedText code too.

Comment: No. I think that code works on the MacOS and not on the iOS. I ended up using spaces. Its not perfect, but it kinda works.